# Print an element in an array matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to print an element in an array but can't seem to get it. The places I've looked have said to access an array you should put parenthesis or curly brackets around the index of the array you are looking at but neither of those seem to work.

```
arr = [1 2 3];

disp('print 2: ');
disp(arr{1}); %disp(arr(1)); doesn't seem to work either
```

I'd be pretty happy for any solid links that can clear up my confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need normal brackets instead of curly: `disp(arr(1))`.

I'd also prefer [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) instead of `disp` for what you're trying, so you can get rid of the linebreak:

```
sprintf('Print 2: %f\n',arr(1));
```

The curly ones are for [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).

Comment: Don't forget that Matlab starts indexing from 1, not 0. So the second element of `arr` is `arr(2)`.

Comment: yeah, he'll see that probably when executing this :p